# Equivalent to rowMeans() for min()

Tags: r, optimization

I have seen this question being asked multiple times on the R mailing list, but still could not find a satisfactory answer.

Suppose I a matrix `m`

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(10000000), ncol=10)
```

I can get the mean of each row by:

```
system.time(rowMeans(m))  
   user  system elapsed   
  0.100   0.000   0.097
```

But obtaining the minimum value of each row by

```
system.time(apply(m,1,min))  
   user  system elapsed   
 16.157   0.400  17.029
```

takes more than 100 times as long, is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use `pmin`, but you would have to get each column of your matrix into a separate vector.  One way to do that is to convert it to a data.frame then call `pmin` via `do.call` (since data.frames are lists).

```
system.time(do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(m)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.940   0.000   0.949 
system.time(apply(m,1,min))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   16.84    0.00   16.95
```

Comment: I like the use of `do.call`. I thought of `pmin`, but didn't think of a slick way to incorporate it. All the cool kids seem to be able to use `do.call` to achieve their goals...I need to do some reading on this.

Comment: `do.call` comes in handy when you want to be able to create function arguments dynamically (generally when the number of arguments passed via `...` isn't known).

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! with pmin.int() it was even a tiny bit faster

Comment: Hadley have nice vocabulary of [functions that you need to know](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/vocabulary). There is `pmin` too.

Comment: Some variation of your answer: `do.call(pmin, lapply(seq_len(ncol(m)), function(i) m[,i]))`

Comment: `@Marek`, how to handle NA values in your solution?

Comment: @danas.zuokas: `do.call(pmin, c(na.rm=TRUE, lapply(...)))`

Answer (score 18):

Quite late to the party, but as the author of [matrixStats](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixStats/index.html) and in case someone spots this, please note that `matrixStats::rowMins()` is very fast these days, e.g.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(Biobase)     # rowMin()
library(matrixStats) # rowMins()
options(digits=3)

m <- matrix(rnorm(10000000), ncol=10) 

stats <- microbenchmark(
  rowMeans(m), ## A benchmark by OP
  rowMins(m),
  rowMin(m),
  do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(m)),
  apply(m, MARGIN=1L, FUN=min),
  times=10
)

> stats
Unit: milliseconds
                             expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max
                      rowMeans(m)   77.7   82.7   85.7   84.4   90.3   98.2
                       rowMins(m)   72.9   74.1   88.0   79.0   90.2  147.4
                        rowMin(m)  341.1  347.1  395.9  383.4  395.1  607.7
  do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(m))  326.4  357.0  435.4  401.0  437.6  657.9
 apply(m, MARGIN = 1L, FUN = min) 3761.9 3963.8 4120.6 4109.8 4198.7 4567.4
```

Comment: @HenirkB it would be great if matrixStats rowMins also worked on data.frames, (without the need of transform it to matrix first)

Comment: @skan, unfortunately it's not obvious that this belongs to matrixStats for various reasons, please see https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/issues/18

Answer (score 9):

If you want to stick to CRAN packages, then both the `matrixStats` and the `fBasics` packages have the function `rowMins` [*note the `s` which is not in the `Biobase` function*] and a variety of other row and column statistics.

Answer (score 5):

```
library("sos")
findFn("rowMin")
```

gets a hit in the `Biobase` package, from Bioconductor ...

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Biobase")

m <- matrix(rnorm(10000000), ncol=10)
system.time(rowMeans(m))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.132   0.148   0.279 
system.time(apply(m,1,min))
##   user  system elapsed 
## 11.825   1.688  13.603
library(Biobase)
system.time(rowMin(m))
##    user  system elapsed 
##  0.688   0.172   0.864
```

Not as fast as `rowMeans`, but a lot faster than `apply(...,1,min)`

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of the sos package and rowMin solves my problem too.

Comment: Care to time the `do.call` solution as well?

Answer (score 5):

I've been meaning to try out the new `compiler` package in R 2.13.0. This essentially follows the post outlined by Dirk [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/04/12/).

```
library(compiler)
library(rbenchmark)
rowMin <- function(x, ind) apply(x, ind, min)
crowMin <- cmpfun(rowMin)

benchmark(
      rowMin(m,1)
    , crowMin(m,1)
    , columns=c("test", "replications","elapsed","relative")
    , order="relative"
    , replications=10)
)
```

And the results:

```
           test replications elapsed relative
2 crowMin(m, 1)           10 120.091   1.0000
1  rowMin(m, 1)           10 122.745   1.0221
```

Anticlimatic to say the least, though looks like you've gotten some other good options.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will have to look deeper into your answer, that's new terrain for me :)

Comment: Compiler is better in optimization of explicit loops. Try e.g.: `rowMin <- function(x) {n <- nrow(x);r <- numeric(n);for (i in 1:n) r[i] <- min(x[i,]);r}`

Answer (score 2):

Not particularly R-idiosyncratic, but surely the fastest method is just to use `pmin` and loop over columns:

```
x <- m[,1]
for (i in 2:ncol(m)) x <- pmin(x, m[,i])
```

On my machine that takes just 3 times longer than rowMeans for the 1e+07x10 matrix, and is slightly faster than the `do.call` method via `data.frame`.

Comment: And another speed gain by `pmin(m[,1], m[,2], m[,3], m[,4], m[,5], m[,6], m[,7], m[,8], m[,9], m[,10])`. Joshua `as.data.frame` is time consuming.

Comment: not speedy for typing though, or general to different inputs :)

Comment: I add more general solution in comment to Joshua answer.