# How to find if we have two or more equal minimum values in specific columns

Tags: r

I have this problem I was hoping someone could help.

I have a very large data frame (close to 20000000 observations)in R with about 43 columns, in four of those columns I need to find whether there is more than one equal minimum value below 200, then if we have rows where more than one column has the same value that meets this criteria I need to flag that row to TRUE (in a a new flag column). Please note that those columns include NA values, and `NA`s should not be used (when NA is present in the columns being compared, returns NA)

the goal is to look up the values in each row for columns a1 to a4 and find whether the minimum value that does not exceed 200, occurs in more than one column per row

for simplicity let's say that this is how my data data look like

```
head(mydata)
t1  a1  a2  a3  a4 
34  NA  NA  NA  NA
26  10  15  250 150
34  20  20  100 30 
35  5   5   10  5  
25  45  100 3   45
31 400 310 500 310 
")
```

the goal is to look up the values in each row for columns a1 to a4 and find whether the minimum value that does not exceed 200, occurs in more than one column per row, if it does return true if not, false

the expected result will look like this

```
head(mydata)
t1  a1  a2  a3  a4  flag
34  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
26  10  15  250 150 FALSE
34  20  20  100 30  TRUE
35  5   5   10  5   TRUE
25  45  100 3   45  FALSE
31 400 310 500 310  FALSE
")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you going row-wise or columnwise?

Comment: @NelsonGon going row-wise

Comment: thank you so much everyone, will try these solutions now!

Comment: sorry it's taking a bit to try your answers. The volume of data I have is starting to slow down my machines, but will try and let you know asap. Thank you for the very quick answers !

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! all the solutions give me the expected result! I found @RuiBarradas method particularly easy to generalize, and also faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a large dataset, the following might be fast. It uses package `matrixStats`, function `rowMins`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338517/equivalent-to-rowmeans-for-min/28820351#28820351).

```
icol <- grepl("^a", names(mydata))
min_row <- matrixStats::rowMins(as.matrix(mydata[icol]))

mydata$flag <- rowSums(mydata[icol] == min_row) > 1 & min_row < 200
```

Comment: thanks so much, this works nicely with my data size and format!

Comment: @HelioCuve You can accept an answer that works for you by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R way to do it

```
#Get the column indices where a1, a2, a3 and a4 are there
inds <- match(paste0("a", 1:4), names(df))

#Get row-wise minimum
min_val <- do.call(pmin, df[inds])

#Check if there are more than one occurrence of minimum value 
# and if minimum value is less than 200.
df$flag <- rowSums(df[inds] == min_val) > 1 & min_val < 200

df
#  t1  a1  a2  a3  a4  flag
#1 34  NA  NA  NA  NA    NA
#2 26  10  15 250 150 FALSE
#3 34  20  20 100  30  TRUE
#4 35   5   5  10   5  TRUE
#5 25  45 100   3  45 FALSE
#6 31 400 310 500 310 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this help you?:

```
mydata$flag=apply(mydata,1,function(x){  # iterate through rows
    x=na.omit(x);        # omit NAs in a row (optional)
    tab=table(x[x<200]); # count numbers of all row values below 200
    if(any(tab>1)){      # check if any values are not unique
          return(TRUE)
          }else{
          return(FALSE)
         }})
```

You can choose to include or omit `NA` values or not.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! I cannot say how fast my code would be in comparison to the 2 below answers so I'd recommend checking them out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `purrr` solution. I create the data frame.

```r
# Define data frame
df <- read.table(text = " t1  a1  a2  a3  a4 
                  34  NA  NA  NA  NA
                  26  10  15  250 150
                  34  20  20  100 30 
                  35  5   5   10  5  
                  25  45  100 3   45
                  31 400 310 500 310 ", header = TRUE)
```

Next, I load the library.

```r
# Load library
library(purrr)
```

Then, I create the flag, running through each row using `pmap_lgl`, which returns a logical. This line checks if there is more than one minimum value *and* that the minimum is below 200. The first column is omitted from the calculation. If there are `NA` values in each row, an `NA` will be created.

```r
# Create flag
df$flag <- pmap_lgl(df, function(...)(sum(c(...)[-1] == min(c(...)[-1])) > 1) & min(c(...)[-1]) < 200)
```

This gives the following:

```r
# Examine result
df
#>   t1  a1  a2  a3  a4  flag
#> 1 34  NA  NA  NA  NA    NA
#> 2 26  10  15 250 150 FALSE
#> 3 34  20  20 100  30  TRUE
#> 4 35   5   5  10   5  TRUE
#> 5 25  45 100   3  45 FALSE
#> 6 31 400 310 500 310 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One possibility involving `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(flag = exec(pmin, !!!.[-1]),
        flag = rowSums(.[-1] == flag) > 1 & flag < 200)

  t1  a1  a2  a3  a4  flag
1 34  NA  NA  NA  NA    NA
2 26  10  15 250 150 FALSE
3 34  20  20 100  30  TRUE
4 35   5   5  10   5  TRUE
5 25  45 100   3  45 FALSE
6 31 400 310 500 310 FALSE
```

Here it checks whether the occurrence of row-wise minimum is greater than 1 and whether the row-wise minimum is below 200.