# How do I add a column to a data frame consisting of minimum values from other columns?

Tags: r, min

How do I add a column to a data frame consisting of the minimum values from other columns? So in this case, to create a third column that will have the values 1, 2 and 2?

`df = data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:2)`

Comment: `library(tidyverse) df %>% mutate(C = pmin(A, B))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apply()` function to do this. See below.

```
df$C <- apply(df, 1, min)
```

The second argument allows you to choose the dimension in which you want `min` to be applied, in this case 1, applies min to all columns in each row separately.

You can choose specific columns from the dataframe, as follows:

```
df$newCol <- apply(df[c('A','B')], 1, min)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does answer my question. But let's say there were three columns to begin with and I only wanted the minimum values from the first two. Can I use apply() and specify that I want the minimum values specifically of columns A and B?

Comment: I added the answer to this, to my answer. Please see above.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the parallel minimum function with `do.call` to apply it on all your columns:

```
df$C <- do.call(pmin, df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do simply:

```
df$C <- apply(FUN=min,MARGIN=1,X=df)
```

Or:

```
df[, "C"] <- apply(FUN=min,MARGIN=1,X=df)
```

or:

```
df["C"] <- apply(FUN=min,MARGIN=1,X=df)
```

Instead of `apply`, you could also use `data.farme(t(df))`, where `t` transposes `df`, because `sapply` would traverse a data frame column-wise applying the given function. So the rows must be made columns. Since `t` outputs always a matrix, you need to make it a `data.frame()` again.

```
df$C <- sapply(data.frame(t(df)), min)
```

Or one could use the fact that `ifelse` is vectorized:

```
df$C <- with(df, ifelse(A<B,A,B))
```

Or:

```
df$C <- ifelse(df$A < df$B, df$A, df$B)
```

#### matrixStats

```
# install.packages("matrixStats")

matrixStats::rowMins(as.matrix(df))
```

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28820351/9690090) the fastest.
`apply`-type functions use lists and are always quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C = min(A, B))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise: 
      A     B     C
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     4     1
2     2     3     2
3     3     2     2
```

Using input with equal values across rows:

```
df = data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:2)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(C = min(A, B))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Rowwise: 
       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1    11     1
 2     2    10     2
 3     3     9     3
 4     4     8     4
 5     5     7     5
 6     6     6     6
 7     7     5     5
 8     8     4     4
 9     9     3     3
10    10     2     2
```

Comment: Does this not fail if you have the same value in the row i.e. if A[1] = B[1] = 1, the output should be 1,1,2 in that case whereas you will get 1,2,2

Comment: @cgvoller Does the edit answer what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform(`) to add the `min` column as the output of `pmin(a, b)` and access the elements of `df` without indexing:

```
df <- transform(df, min = pmin(a, b))
```

or

In `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(a = 1:3, b = 4:2)
DT[,  min := pmin(a, b)]
```